# JAR file is not showing images

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am working on an *School Management Application* in Java. When i build a JAR file & open it in Winrar, all the resources including **images** folder are there.  All is going good in NetBeans but when i run the JAR file, it doesn't display the images.

**My directory loos like this:**

- sms

  - myApp.java
- images

  - all required images here..

**The code is:**

```
iconAdd = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../images/add.png"));
add = new JButton(iconAdd);
add.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 100));
add.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.decode("#a2bdbf"), 1, true));
add.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(12));
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
leftPane.add(add, gbc);
```

Like above, i'm adding all the required images. In NetBeans, it is working fine but the JAR file is not displaying any image. I know there are similar questions but that didn't help me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.